# I want to call API in codeigniter. I got a HTTP request error kindly guide me

Tags: codeigniter

I want to call API in codeigniter. I got a HTTP request error kindly guide me.

A PHP Error was encountered
    Severity: Warning

```
Message: file_get_contents(http:/.@kk.com&password=kk&devicemedium=WEB): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed

Filename: controllers/search.php

Line Number: 602
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a malformed url !

file_get_contents(http:/.@kk.com&password=kk&devicemedium=WEB)

```
"http:/.@kk.com"
```

Did you call the good url ?

Curl is better than `file_get_contents` (see : http://bitly.com/1zrYkDN)
Try this and don't forget to activate the CURL extention in your php.ini

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'http://new.ezeeinfosolutions.com/busservices/auth/getAuthToken?namespaceCode=demo&username=' . $username . '&password=' . $password . '&devicemedium=' . $medium,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'cURL Request'
));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);
```

Comment: sir i have given exactly like this  http://new.ezeeinfosolutions.com/busservices/auth/getAuthToken?namespaceCode=demo&username=$username&password=$password&devicemedium=$medium

Comment: with the $username(and other) variables in the url ?

Comment: After i'advice you to not use file_get_contents for calling an api.
try to call API with CURL ! i can write you an example if you want